# Error when compiling my program node.js - rrdtool : unknown DS name '' "

Tags: node.js, rrdtool

var rrdtool = require('rrdtool');

var start = rrdtool.now() - 10;
var db = rrdtool.create('test.rrd', { start: start, step: 1 } , ['DS:test:GAUGE:1:0:100','RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:10']);

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable. Indent 4 spaces, or use the format button.

Comment: The code looks correct; despite being awkwardly formatted the correct parameters are there.  Are you sure this is the part giving the errors? The error message may be coming from a different part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the ds name, but in the next command.

```
db.update(start + 0, 15);
```

If you leave only the lines that you provided the code will compile without errors.
To correct the error from the update method go to the proc.js file (node_modules/rrdtool/lib/proc.js) and change the update method to something like this.

```js
exports.update = function (file, ts, values, cb) {
  var cmd = [ts];

  cmd.push(values);

  exec(['update', file, cmd.join(':')], function (err) {
    cb(err);
  });
};
```

Before the change, it did not form the rrdtool command correctly, the command looked like `update --template timestamp`, instead of `update timestamp:value`. In my example the timestamp is start + 0, and the value is 15.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in update method. If you try to do something like this:

```
db.update(start + 1, 90)
```

It will produce the error. You should pass the object instead of the value. Something like this will work:

```
db.update(start + 0, {test: 15});
```